# Javascript pyramid name display

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck with this javascript. I have to make it look like this (Prompt name, for example Peter)

`p
pe
pet
pete
peter
pete
pet
pe
p`

My javascript looks like this

It is for school, It's not nessesary to make the script for me but could you tell me what i'm doing wrong? I'm not getting any result at all.

Thank you!

Rayco

```
var naam = parseInt(prompt("typ hier je naam"));
    var lengte = naam.length;
    var x = 0;

    for (x = 0; x <lengte; x++) {
        document.write("<br>" + naam.substring(0,x));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` turns typed numbers into actual numbers. It looks like you are using `parseInt` on actual letters - which will return `NaN` and hence will not work out as intended for you.

If you remove the `parseInt`, you will get a result.

```js
var naam = prompt("typ hier je naam");
var lengte = naam.length;
var x = 0;

for (x = 0; x <lengte; x++) {
  document.write("<br>" + naam.substring(0,x));
}
```

Comment: It does not break the JS, it returns NaN which has a length of undefined

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
    var naam = prompt("typ hier je naam");
    var lengte = naam.length;
    var x = 0;

    for (x = 0; x <=lengte; x++) {
        document.write("<br>" + naam.substring(0,x));
        if(x==lengte)
            for(var y = naam.length; y>=0; y--){
                if(y!=naam.length)
                    document.write("<br>" + naam.substring(0,y));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the string returned by prompt, it returns a string and you can get the length from it using `.length`.

```
var naam = prompt("typ hier je naam");
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to see that your parseInt was for sure not what you wanted since it returns NaN (Not a Number) which has a length of undefined

Also do not use document.write - it will wipe the page if you call it after the page has loaded.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("naam"), naam = prompt("typ hier je naam");
for (var i = 0; i < naam.length; i++) {
  var chars = naam.substring(0, i);
  div.innerHTML+="<br>" + chars;
}
for (var i = naam.length; i>=0; i--) {
  var chars = naam.substring(0, i);
  div.innerHTML+="<br>" + chars;
}
```

```html
<div id="naam"></div>
```